# Encoding a password with the Spring Security Grails plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

In my Grails 2.5.1 project, I'm using the spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 plugin and getting this error:

```
Error initializing the application: Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object
```

Here is my BootStrap :

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def springSecurityService
        def userRole = SecurityRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_USER") ?: new SecurityRole(authority:"ROLE_USER").save(flush:true)
        def adminRole = SecurityRole.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") ?: new SecurityRole(authority:"ROLE_ADMIN").save(flush:true)

        def user = new User(username:"user" ,password:springSecurityService.encodePassword("123"),enable:true ).save(flush:true)
        def admin = new User(username:"admin" ,password:springSecurityService.encodePassword("1234"),enable:true ).save(flush:true)
        SecurityUserSecurityRole.create(user, userRole)
        SecurityUserSecurityRole.create(admin, adminRole)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the location of `def springSecurityService`. As you have it declared, it's a local variable of the `init` closure. It's not a candidate for dependency injection, so nothing initializes it and it's null.

To use dependency injection, declare beans as class-scope properties, not local variables (of closures or methods). The reason that this works is that the Groovy compiler converts a property declaration into a private field with a getter and a setter. Spring doesn't have any support for Groovy properties, but can autowire by name (and this is the Grails default) when there's a setter method that coincides with the bean name. So since the Groovy compiler adds a `void setSpringSecurityService(springSecurityService)` method for you, Spring sees it and invokes it since the method's "property" name matches the bean you want. If you declare a local variable, it's completely ignored.

So your code should look like this:

```
def springSecurityService

def init = { servletContext ->
    ...
}
```

But then you'll hit the second problem with your code. Assuming you haven't changed the auto-hashing logic in your `User` class, you'll be encoding twice. Once in BootStrap, and again in the domain class. If you do this nobody will be able to authenticate. Pick one - hash explicitly like you're doing and remove the code from the domain class, or leave the domain class code and just set the cleartext password. If you choose option #2, your code (also cleaned up to use `findOrSaveBy` and to replace all of those unnecessary eager flush calls with one) should look like

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = {
        def userRole = SecurityRole.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_USER')
        def adminRole = SecurityRole.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')

        def user = new User(username: 'user' ,password: '123').save()
        def admin = new User(username: 'admin' ,password: '1234').save()
        SecurityUserSecurityRole.create(user, userRole)
        SecurityUserSecurityRole.create(admin, adminRole)

        User.withSession { it.flush() }
    }
}
```

An even better approach would be to move this code to a transactional service. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer , you made it clear for me now , but i'm facing a new thing , nothing stored in the DB except the **userRole** and **adminRole** , the users are not stored !! do you see anything in the code ?

Comment: It's probably a validation error - did you add a new required property to the `User` class? All properties are `nullable:false` by default. I almost never use `failOnError` because of the huge cost of throwing a validation exception, but when you have hard-coded values that you expect to be valid like here (another case would be data in tests), I would use it to make the problem obvious and to fail fast. Change `save()` to `save(failOnError: true)` for the two users and it should show what's missing.

Comment: ya it was some validations errors , really appreciate your support , by the way do you got any helpful and useful resources for Grails to give me good push as i'm experienced java developer but i'm new to Grails and i need to finish a small project with it .

Comment: See the books at https://grails.org/wiki/Books - "The Definitive Guide to Grails 2" and "Grails in Action" are the most comprehensive